# Simple example of CALayers in an NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer

I am trying to add several CALayers to an NSView but my view remains empty when shown:

Here is my code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    self.layer = [CALayer layer];
    self.wantsLayer = YES;
    CALayer *newLayer = [CALayer layer];
    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
    newLayer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
    newLayer.contents = (id)[image CGImageForProposedRect:NULL context:NULL hints:nil];
    newLayer.frame = NSMakeRect(100,100,100,100);//NSMakeRect(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height);
    newLayer.position  = CGPointMake(20,20);
    [self.layer addSublayer:newLayer];

}
return self;
```

}

DO have any idea (or example of code) to perform this task?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code to set up the layer needs to be in the awakeFromNib method, not in the initWithFrame function.

The explanation why :)

In the nib file your view is marked as not needing a layer, so the flow is

- you set your layers in the initWithFrame: method
- the nib file properties are set up wiping out your layers.

You could also leave your code the way it is, and tell interface builder that your custom view needs a layer.

Comment: Thanks! it was the issue. Could you please now explain me why?

Comment: I believe initWithFrame will not be called as initWithCoder will instead.

Comment: @iain Is this still the case? I seem to be successful in setting my layers inside init now.

Comment: @Sam: I believe it should still be the case, but if you mean init rather than initWithCoder: then your view isn't going to get an awakeFromNib call which would wipe the layer out, so in the case of creating a view programmatically, then the correct place for setting up the layers would be initWithFrame:/init